# ioredis BLPOP does not work for multiple list's as arguments

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I'm using ioredis as a queuing system for my worker.

As per the documentation, BLPOP takes any number of list and pops the required item from them.

Am I missing here some important detail on redis/BLPOP ?

Any help would really be appreciated.

For a single queue/list it works totally perfect.

This blocks all of them.

```
getMessage(callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.rclient.blpop(
        QUEUE_TYPES.INVOICE_QUEUE,
        QUEUE_TYPES.AUDIT_MUTATION_QUEUE,
        QUEUE_TYPES.AUDIT_QUEUE,
        QUEUE_TYPES.ERROR_QUEUE,
        1,
        (err, res) => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          else resolve(callback(err, res));
        },
      );
    });
  }
```

This works perfect.

```
getMessage(callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.rclient.blpop(
        QUEUE_TYPES.INVOICE_QUEUE,
        1,
        (err, res) => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          else resolve(callback(err, res));
        },
      );
    });
  }
```